# How'd I use the Pyplot function in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm having trouble trying to display my results after the program is finished. I'm expecting to see a velocity vs position graph, but for some reason, it's not showing up. Is there something wrong with my code.

```
import numpy 
from matplotlib import pyplot 
import time,sys


#specifying parameters

nx=41 # number of space steps
nt=25  #number of time steps
dt=0.025 #width between time intervals
dx=2/(nx-1) #width between space intervals 
c=1 # the speed of the initial wave



#boundary conditions
u = numpy.ones(nx) 
u[int(0.5/dx):int(1/(dx+1))] = 2

un = numpy.ones(nx)

#initializing the velocity function
for i in range(nt):
un= u.copy()
for i in range(1,nx):
    u[i]= un[i] -c*(dt/dx)*(u[i]-u[i-1])


pyplot.xlabel('Position')
pyplot.ylabel('Velocity')
pyplot.plot(numpy.linspace(0,2,nx),u)
```

Comment: Try adding `pyplot.show()` at the end

Comment: Your, un= u.copy isn't properly indented.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here

1. You don't need to write out the full name of the packages you are importing. You can just use aliasing to call those packages and use them with those aliases later on. This, for example.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   ```
2. Your dx value initalization will give you 0 beause you are dividing 2 by 40 which will give you a zero. You can initialize the value of dx by making one of the values in that expression a float, so something like this.

   ```
   dx=float(2)/(nx-1) #width between space intervals
   ```

As Meowcolm Law in the comments suggested in the comments, add pyplot.show() to 
show the graph. This is what the edited version of your code will like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import time,sys


#specifying parameters

nx=41 # number of space steps
nt=25  #number of time steps
dt=0.025 #width between time intervals
dx=float(2)/(nx-1) #width between space intervals 
c=1 # the speed of the initial wave



#boundary conditions
u = np.ones(nx) 
u[int(0.5/dx):int(1/(dx+1))] = 2
un = np.ones(nx)

#initializing the velocity function
for i in range(nt):
    un= u.copy()
for i in range(1,nx):
    u[i]= un[i] -c*(dt/dx)*(u[i]-u[i-1])


plt.xlabel('Position')
plt.ylabel('Velocity')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0,2,nx),u)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
%matplotlib inline
```

in order to view the plot inside  the notebook. I missed this step following the same guide.